# ISO Weeknumber formula explanation

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

can anyone breakdown this ISOWeekNumber formula and explain to me in detail how it formula works?

```
=INT((A1-WEEKDAY(A1,2)-DATE(YEAR(A1+4-WEEKDAY(A1,2)),1,4))/7)+2
```

and this one?

```
=INT((A1-DATE(YEAR(A1-WEEKDAY(A1-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1-WEEKDAY(A1-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)
```

another one,

```
=INT((A1-SUM(MOD(DATE(YEAR(A1-MOD(A1-2,7)+3),1,2),{1E+99;7})*{1;-1})+5)/7)
```

and another,

```
=INT((A1-DATE(YEAR(A1-WEEKDAY(A1-1)+4),1,3)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1-WEEKDAY(A1-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7)
```

and another,

```
=1+INT((A1-DATE(YEAR(A1+4-WEEKDAY(A1+6)),1,5)+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1+4-WEEKDAY(A1+6)),1,3)))/7)
```

which one is correct or more accurate as an ISO Week Number, as i cannot find any explanation to the logic behind these formulae?

Comment: The first is clearly using ISO 8601, refer to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering

Comment: i guess this guy "SnB" provides the best explanation (with examples) for ISO Week Number.


[VBA for Smarties](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_ISO_weeknummer_en.html)

Answer (score 0):

1st formula; It is developed by barry houdini. (See the following link)
http://addinbox.sakura.ne.jp/Excel_Tips20E.htm#barry

2nd formula; It is developed by Frank Kabel. (See the following link)
http://addinbox.sakura.ne.jp/Excel_Tips20E.htm#MSDN

3rd formula; I do not understand.

4th formula; It is the same as the 2nd formula.

5th formula; It transforms the 2nd formula. (See below)

```
WEEKDAY(A1+6) is equal with WEEKDAY(A1-1).
DATE(any, 1, 5) is equal with (DATE(any, 1, 3)+2).

=1+INT((A1 - DATE(YEAR(A1+4-WEEKDAY(A1+6)),1,5) + WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1+4-WEEKDAY(A1+6)),1,3)) )/7)
=(7/7)+INT((A1 - DATE(YEAR(A1-WEEKDAY(A1-1)+4),1,5) + WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1-WEEKDAY(A1-1)+4),1,3)) )/7)
=INT((A1 - DATE(YEAR(A1-WEEKDAY(A1-1)+4),1,5) + WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1-WEEKDAY(A1-1)+4),1,3)) + 7)/7)
=INT((A1-(DATE(YEAR(A1-WEEKDAY(A1-1)+4),1,3) + 2) + WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1-WEEKDAY(A1-1)+4),1,3)) + 7)/7)
=INT((A1-DATE(YEAR(A1-WEEKDAY(A1-1)+4),1,3) + WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1-WEEKDAY(A1-1)+4),1,3)) + 7 - 2 )/7)
=INT((A1-DATE(YEAR(A1-WEEKDAY(A1-1)+4),1,3) + WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1-WEEKDAY(A1-1)+4),1,3)) + 5 )/7)
```

AddinBox ( K.Tsunoda ) in Japan.

The link mentioned above is my site. (Change URL link. Sep 10 2017)